# Powershell - Implementing looping to access elements in a hash algorithm

Tags: powershell, hash, filehash

The function I wrote here accepts three mandatory parameters: an input file, a list containing at least one hash algorithm(s), and an output file that saves the hash values of that input file. This function attempts to accept three needed parameters: input file, list of at least one hash algorithms, and output file that saves the hashed values of that input file. I am trying to complete the function by writing the code needed to efficiently and effectively implement this function in the specified block. I am attempting to implement some form of looping to access the elements in  $hashAlgorithm.

```
function Return-FileHash { 
param ( 
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
[ValidateSet("SHA1","SHA256","SHA384","SHA512","MD5")] 
[STRING[]] 
# the array list that contains one or more hash algorithm input for Get-FileHash cmdlet 
$hashAlgorithm, 
[Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
# the document or executable input/InputStream for Get-FileHash cmdlet 
$filepath, 
[Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
# the output file that contains the hash values of $filepath 
$hashOutput 
) 
#============================ begin ==================== 
# Here, I am trying to use a loop expression to implement this
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $hashAlgorithm.Length; $i++)
{
Get -FileHash $hashAlgorithm -SHA1 | $hashOutput
}

# === end ================= 
Return-FileHash
```

I get this:

```
At line:19 char:38
+ Get -FileHash $hashAlgorithm -SHA1 | $hashOutput
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:26
+ function Return-FileHash {
+                          ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the individual elements of `$hashAlgorithm` in the `for` loop, index into it with the current value of `$i`:

```bsh
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $hashAlgorithm.Length; $i++) {
    Get-FileHash $filepath -Algorithm $hashAlgorithm[$i] | ...
}
```

Alternatively use a `foreach()` loop:

```bsh
foreach($algo in $hashAlgorithm.Length) {
    Get-FileHash $filepath -Algorithm $algo | ...
}
```

To output to a file at path `$hashOutput`, either use the file redirection operators:

```
# `>` means "overwrite"
Get-FileHash $filepath -Algorithm $hashAlgorithm[$i] > $hashOutput
# `>>` means "append"
Get-FileHash $filepath -Algorithm $hashAlgorithm[$i] >> $hashOutput
```

Or pass `$hashOutput` as an argument to a command that writes the output to disk:

```
Get-FileHash $filepath -Algorithm $hashAlgorithm[$i] | Add-Content -Path $hashOutput
```